# Rear disk brake fluid leak

Tags: disc-brake

I tried to adjust the pads on my rear brakes but it caused some mineral oil to leak. Not sure why. I only used couple screws to allow brake pads to adjust. What could cause the leakage? What should be next step to fix? Will adding oil help?

Comment: which screws? could be important, see if you can include a photo of the brake and which screws you have adjusted so they can be ruled out

Comment: The screws allow the pads move away from each other so it makes room for the disk to align. I do not have the bike with me now to make pictures unfortunately.

Comment: make and model of brakes will be helpful too.

Comment: Adding oil won't help stop a leak.  (source, I own an english car and the oil leaks only stop when its empty.)

Comment: If you're unsure what to do you'd rather refer to your LBS. Working on brakes without proper knowledge is dangerous and potentially lethal.

Comment: So my LBS replaced the whole rear brake system from Promax to Shimano. But rotor start touching the new pads after braking. They say I have to bike for some time before everything will settle. Is it true? I am not convinced though

Comment: Most modern brakes will self-adjust for pad wear as long as your pistons are clean and move freely. This sounds more likely to be an issue with the caliper being misaligned. Do not meddle with any of the hydraulic attachments, this will just result in your brakes requiring a bleed. You can try to realign the caliper by loosening the bolts holding the caliper to the frame, adjusting the caliper alignment (centreline should align with the rotor disk) then tighten the mounting bolts back up.

Comment: I figured it out too and it worked. Thank you T_Bacon for confirming the same. Actually what I found the two bolts we're not tightened enough resulting misalignment after hard brake. So I aligned caliper and tightened properly. Biked for an hour without any issues. How come those guys from lbs were not able to resolve it? They are from Sport Check and licensed for the job. Unbelievable. And you do not know the whole story of my interaction with them...and it's long one.